# How do you hide API Key when using Spring boot with Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have seen examples with Gradle, where API key is stored in `gradle.properties` file.
After that modifying the `build.gradle` file and then using a variable for it in Java app.

How can I do something similar in a Maven Project?

Comment: Is the `gradle.properties` file one you would commit to source control? If so, that's not a good place to store the API key. Spring Boot's `application.properties` can take values from the environment. How do you run your SB application? Is it managed by something like `OpenShift`?

Comment: As already mentioned checkin in is a bad idea...better using things like vault etc. ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but such files usually go into source control, like GitHub, and thus I wouldn't put sensitive content in there. An everything-agnostic way is putting them into environment variables and reading via `System.getenv()`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: Its just a quick local webapp test which I want to put to github without exposing the keys.

Comment: Try JASYPT- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt
or Vault - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60723956/securely-storing-secrets-of-a-spring-boot-application-in-hashicorp-vault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your api key to don't be pushed to your git remote repository, and then use it on your project using the **@Value** annotation.

You can configure the file containing your api key as "**application-dev.properties**" so it can't be pushed to the remote repository.

> .gitignore

```
application-dev.properties
```

It can be created under

**/resources/application-dev.properties**

You can define your api key there

> application-dev.properties

```
apiKey=your_key
```

And then in some class that you want to use it

> SomeClass.java

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Value("${apiKey}")
    private String apiKey;

}
```

Then you can use this variable apiKey as your **api key**, hiding the actual value.